# Link to install WindowsBuilder in latest Eclipse -- Luna 4.4.1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

When I search on the WindowBuilderPro plugin for the current/latest Luna Eclipse release (4.4.1), the URL I need to give to Eclipse under Help->Install New Software is blurred-out, for example here:

[example link to install WindowBuilderPro plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201406251200/4.4/)

Where do I get the actual link I need to give to Eclipse in Help->Install New Software?

Comment: Note I've seen this blurred out "strategy" on several websites.

Answer (score 0):

It is very interesting. The URL is just what you have noticed.
Here:
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201406251200/4.4/

Drag the URL above and drop it into the "Work with" field of the "Install" dialog 
(Click and drag the icon in front of the URL in your browser's address bar to drag the URL)